# Powershell - adding a string to each row

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv with over 1,000 rows.
In powershell how do I add a fixed string (e.g. "File1")to each row of the csv file.
For example:
Cat,dog,mouse  should become file1,cat,dog,mouse.

Hopefully this is clear. Thanks for assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
Import-Csv "CSV FILE Path" |
  Select-Object @{n='YOUR NEW COLUMN HEADER NAME';e={"file1"}},* |
    Export-Csv "CSV FILE Path"
```

Comment: Thanks Wasif,
That seems to do it.  I will experiment further.

Comment: See this link which show the input and output.
https://www.screencast.com/t/isY7Eqj6

I would prefer the output without any quotation marks.
Also, I do not want the top two rows of the output.
I used this syntax;

import-csv input17.txt|select-object @{e={File1}},*|export-csv Output4

Comment: Actually, I just want to remove the first row, beginning, "#Type Selected.."

Comment: Thanks Doug,
I have got rid of the header row.
Do you know how I can get rid of the double quotes?

Example:
"File1","Row3   field1  field2  field3"

Comment: I guess that I really dont want a csv file output.
Just an ordinary text file (not entirely sure of the difference)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your latest comment, I think the fastest way here is to read the file line-by-line and output that same line with the wanted prefix attached.

Something like:

```
$prefix = 'File1'
$result = switch -File 'D:\Test\TheInputFile.csv' {
    default { "$prefix,$_" }
}

$result | Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\TheOutputFile.csv'
```

If the input file is a csv with headers, you'll need to supply a new column header for the inserted field:

```
$prefix    = 'File1'
$header    = 'Path'  # or some other not already used column name
$firstLine = $true
$result = switch -File 'D:\Test\TheInputFile.csv' {
    default { 
        if ($firstLine) { "$header,$_"; $firstLine = $false } 
        else { "$prefix,$_" }
    }
}

$result | Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\TheOutputFile.csv'
```

<sup>A CSV file ***is*** a text file. The difference is that in a csv, data is presented in a structured way. Ideally it starts with a header line, defining the field names for the rest of the lines which contain the actual data.

Each field is separated from the next by a specific character, usually a comma or semi-colon or tab.

To make sure a field can also include such a character, these fields must be enclosed in double-quotes.

See [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/348960/what-is-a-csv-file-and-how-do-i-open-it/)</sup>